# takeSnapshot java.lang.NoSuchMethodException for Cassandra snapshot using nodetool

Tags: java, cassandra, nodetool

I am trying to get a snapshot of a cassandra database using the nodetool snapshot tool running on a docker container. More precisely I use the following command

```
nodetool -h cassandra -p 9999 snapshot
```

where cassandra is defined on hosts file.

This yields the following exception :

```
error: takeSnapshot(java.lang.String, java.util.Map, [Ljava.lang.String;)
-- StackTrace --
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: takeSnapshot(java.lang.String, java.util.Map, [Ljava.lang.String;)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.noSuchMethod(PerInterface.java:169)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:135)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:252)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Would someone have an idea of why this is happening ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: what version of Cassandra? on your machine and in container

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that you have incompatible versions of Cassandra inside Docker and on your host - on your host you have either DataStax Enterprise, or Cassandra 4.0 beta that have another set of arguments to the `takeSnapshot` function (it was introduced by this [commit](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/commit/ee9e38b7dc20a3b98e5a68904be35d727ed9c09c#diff-9bf2c26bc294ef9085e16bf287490223665eaa2eb8ec24bcf5bd8653c713644b) 5 years ago).

To fix that problem you need to use the same version of Cassandra to execute command, and the simplest way to do that is to execute it inside the Docker container with `docker exec <container-name> nodetool snapshot <options-if-necessary>`